# Adding my custom post type from plugin to my search results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not able to get search results for my custom post type, generated by a plugin I'm using in wordpress.

If I change the URL after searching from `domain.com/?s=searchterm` 
to `domain.com/?s=searchterm&post_type=customposttype`, it displays only the search results for this custom post type.

My custom post type is searchable and visible. 
I used also these settings in my custom post type.

```
'query_var' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
```

I used also these settings in my custom post type:

```
'query_var' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
```

I have this line in my `searchform.php` file:

```
if ( 'any' != $post_type ) {<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post, customposttype" />}
```

How can I make the search results return results of both `post` and the `customposttype`?

Answer (score 0):

in searchform.php

```
<form method="get" class="searchform" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Search', 'oceanwp' ); ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="post" />
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="customposttype" />
</form>
```

in functions.php

```
function mySearchFilter($query) {
  $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
  if (!$post_type) {
      $post_type = 'any';
  }
  if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', $post_type);
  };
  return $query;
};

add_filter('pre_get_posts','mySearchFilter');
```

Comment: That solution doesnt change anything unfortunately
This is the complete code. I just saw that the first line might be the reason, but dont know why
`$post_type = get_theme_mod( 'ocean_menu_search_source', 'any' ); ?>

<form method="get" class="searchform" id="searchform" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
 
<input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php esc_html_e( 'Search', 'oceanwp' ); ?>">
 <?php if ( 'any' != $post_type ) { ?>
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post_type ); ?>">
 <?php } ?>
</form>`

Comment: I edited my answer. you need extra code in functions.php.I simplified the code in searchform.php for  testing purpose.

Comment: thanks for the edit. But it doesnt give any difference. I copied your suggestions in the files, didnt work and then i tried your suggestion for searchform.php mixed in the original code i had in searchform.php But non of these give any result. 

The search doesnt go through this custom post type for some reason. But at the same time they are searchable if i add `&post_type=customposttype` to the url. But then it returns only posts of this custom type and not the others. So is it possible that i need to specify in a more detailed way the `$post_type`instead of just using `any`?

Comment: When you submit the form with code I posted, what you see in the address bar? that should be like this
`xxxx.com/s=keyword&post_type%5B%5D=page&post_type%5B%5D=customposttype`

Comment: And the source code in web browser should be like this
`<form method="get" class="searchform" id="searchform" action="xxxx"><input type="text" class="field" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search"><input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="page" /><input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="customposttype" />`

Comment: I've only had the time now to try your solution. But the url in the address bar isnt changing..

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the actual query and set the post_type to 'any'.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'any', 's' => $search_term ) );
```

An alternative is to create a filter for search queries, which may be easier (and probably better practice) than adjusting theme code.

```
function search_filter($query) {
  if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
      $query->set('post_type', 'any');
    }
  }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, im going to try to find the actual query. Do you have an idea, in which file it is usually coded in wordpress?

Comment: It really depends on the theme.  Sometimes in search.php.  I have adjusted my answer to provide an alternative solution by using a filter.  You can place this in functions.php.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But no luck so far with it. I'm trying to find out what is happening inside the theme with the searchbar. I think the cause of the problem is how the theme is handling the search. I tested with a new custom post type yesterday which i made with Pods plugin. And even this one is only returned in the searchresults when i add `&post_type=customposttype` to my url